# Find the maximum minor version of a package from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I have the following list of packages and I need to choose one of them based on the bad_version. Example:

```
bad_version = '1.55'
```

```
list = ['1.54', '1.56', '1.57', '1.58', '1.59', '1.60', '1.61', '2.1.3', '2.5.1', '2.9.8', '3.5.0', '3.5.1', '3.6.0', '3.6.1', '3.7.0', '3.7.0-rc1', '3.7.1']
```

The output should be `'1.61'`. However, if the bad_version was `1.61`, since it's the last minor version in the list, it will pick the maximum of the next major which is `'2.9.8'`. also if bad_version was `0.55` it will pick the maximum of the next major which is `1.61`. How would I do that in python

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code. What did not work?

Comment: Is the list of versions you have always sorted correctly or is there the chance, that it might be unsorted? This has an heavy effect on the solution I have in mind, since sorting the version numbers is not trivial...

Comment: @month it will be sorted list for sure, thanks for the question.

Comment: Off-topic: You should never assign `list` with a specific list, since after that, `l2=list({2,3})` would raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: Sure, that was just a variable but can be called anything else, thanks for the note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with

```
def major(version):
    return int(version.split('.')[0])

def next_major_version(bad_version, l_versions):
    bad_maj = major(bad_version)
    offset = 0
    candidates = []
    while candidates == []:
        candidates = [v for v in l_versions if major(v) == bad_maj + offset]
        offset += 1
    if candidates[-1] == bad_version:
        candidates = [v for v in l_versions if major(v) == bad_maj + offset]
    return candidates[-1]

l_versions = ['1.54', '1.56', '1.57', '1.58', '1.59', '1.60', '1.61', '2.1.3', '2.5.1', '2.9.8', '3.5.0', '3.5.1', '3.6.0', '3.6.1', '3.7.0', '3.7.0-rc1', '3.7.1']

# returns '1.61'
next_major_version('1.55', l_versions)

# returns '2.9.8'
next_major_version('1.61', l_versions)

# returns '1.61'
next_major_version('0.55', l_versions)
```

Only problem is that the `while` does not terminate, if `bad_version` is higher than the hightest version in the list. So this only works, if the list of versions is somehow complete.

Comment: works like a charm thanks you so much @month !!

Comment: Found another bug: if `bad_version` is the last of a major version series and there are no versions with `major(v)==major(bad_version)+1`, this will raise a `IndexError`, I guess...
Example: `bad_version='1.51'` and `l_versions=['1.41','1.51','3.0','3.1']`

Comment: Oh yeah, no problem, I can handle that, thanks for the note.

Comment: I had now the issue of `while` does not terminate, how to solve this?

Comment: @JauL Can you give me the list of version numbers that caused the problem?